# MYSQL INNER JOIN where NOT found or specific criteria is found

Tags: mysql

I currently have 2 tables, one with a list of users and one with a list of "checkout" records for a list of devices. I'm trying to build a report to show which users do not currently have something checked out to them, however I'm a bit stumped on how to do this. A sample of data is below:

Users Table Columns:

- ID
- FirstName
- LastName

Device Columns:

- ID
- DeviceName

Checked Out Columns:

- ID
- Device (references Device ID)
- User (references User ID)
- CheckedOutDate (YYYY-MM-DD)
- CheckedInDate (YYYY-MM-DD) - Defaults to 0000-00-00 if the device is "checked out" still.

There are going to be 2 scenarios. One in which a User has never had a Device checked out to them before, and the other where a User HAS had a Device checked out to them but no longer has a device at this time. This is where I'm stuck! I was able to use the below to get the first scenario taken care of, but I'm stumped on how to check for both scenarios at the same time.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN checkedout o
ON u.id = o.user
WHERE o.id IS NULL
```

I tried something like this for the WHERE statement, but it is returning values of users who also still have a device checked out to them.

```
WHERE o.id IS NULL OR o.checkedout != '0000-00-00'
```

Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: I'm currently using 5.6, but will likely be moving to MariaDB 10.x eventually